# How to send notifications to a user

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am able to send notifications to android and apple devices using the "Compose notification" on firebase.
[image: firebase compose notification pic]

I am trying to send a message using cloud functions but I am having a hard time.

I can see all the data I want from the following code snip (cloud function)

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();


exports.onUpdate = functions.firestore
    .document("chat messages/{docId}")
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
      console.log("1");
      console.log(snapshot.data());
      console.log("2");
      console.log(snapshot.data()["User id"] );
      console.log(snapshot.data()["Chat message"] );

      console.log("3");
    });
```

now I need to target the phone to send the notification.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is the solution that worked for me

```
/*
to fix issues:
(cd functions && npx eslint . --fix)
to upload code:
firebase deploy
to do both:
(cd functions && npx eslint . --fix)
firebase deploy
*/


const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
// eslint-disable-next-line max-len
const tokens = ["REDACTED_TOKEN"];

admin.initializeApp();

exports.onCreate = functions.firestore
    .document("chat/{docId}")
    .onCreate((snapshot, context) => {
      console.log(snapshot.data());
      console.log("fake data");
    });

exports.onUpdate = functions.firestore
    .document("chat messages/{docId}")
    .onCreate( (snapshot, context) => {
      const payload = {
        // eslint-disable-next-line max-len
        notification: {title: "Push Title", body: "Push Body", sound: "default"},
        // eslint-disable-next-line max-len
        data: {click_action: "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK", message: "Sample Push Message"},
      };

      try {
        admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokens, payload);
        console.log("NOTIFICATION SEND SUCCESFULLY");
      } catch (e) {
        console.log("ERROR SENDING NOTIFICATION");
        console.log(e);
      }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you see the FCM documentation on [sending messages](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message), specifically on [sending to a specific device](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/send-message#send-messages-to-specific-devices)?

I also recommend having a look at the Cloud Functions sample on [notifying the user when something interesting happens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens). While it triggers on the Realtime Database instead of Firestore, the approach will be very similar to what you need.

Comment: Frank!!!

I got it to work a while back. but i was not able to interpret the docs :(

I posted my solution below.

when I tried to read the docs. it said that "getMessaging" was not a function

Comment: I send you a screen shot on linkedIn